# How to combine a numpy array and a panda series side by side and return a count of the rows which matches

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following:

[image: a panda series and a 1-dimensional numpy array]

[image: data type]

I want to combine these so that it appears as two separate columns side by side (each row corresponds to the same observation on both the panda series and array). Then I want to return a count of the number of rows where the two columns are matching.

Comment: Leocki, it would help us better if you could post the information as actual text which we can copy paste in to help you come to a solution

Comment: On top of what @oppressionslayer said, some more details on what exactly you’re trying to do would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not entirely certain this is correct, so I will update it to take into account any new information.

---

**Pure Python**

```py
num_match_rows = sum(a == b for a, b in zip(my_arr, my_series))
```

---

**Team NumPy**

```py
num_match_rows = np.count_nonzero(np.equal(my_arr, my_series))
```

Comment: @Leockl You’re welcome :) It’s all clear, no further questions?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. Yeah this works and no further questions!

Comment: @Leockl Don’t worry about it! Take one last look if you want, I just added a different method.